# Elasticsearch GET q Param Vs Query Language Body

Tags: elasticsearch

I've been executing this GET against Elasticsearch:

http://localhost:9200/_search?q=test

It works. But what is the equivalent of this in the Query language?

All of the examples in the documentation look like this:

```
GET /twitter/_search
{
    "query" : {
        "term" : { "user" : "kimchy" }
    }
}
```

but I don't want to identify what the value is (the user JSON label, in this case). I just want to do a full search across everything. When I tried doing:

```
GET /_search
{
    "query" : {
        "term" : "test"
    }
}
```

I get `query malformed, no start_object after query name`.

I just want the request body equivalent of the ?q=test. What is it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The equivalent query of `?q=test` is using the `query_string` query, like this:

```
GET /twitter/_search
{
    "query" : {
        "query_string" : { 
            "query" : "test" 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: WOW I poured over the docs and never saw anything like that. May I ask in the docs where this is explained? Thank you

Comment: [Here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-uri-request.html#_parameters_3) on the line describing the `q` parameter ;-)